# php fopen fread images

Tags: php

I am trying to `tcp` an image from my linux php ec2 instance to another server. 
when i echo out the contents of `fopen` and `fread` i can see the image is processed but only halfway 
Does anyonew know what is causing this please, thank you.

```
$imageURL = 'http://ec2-**-***-**-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com/New_Era_For_NASA_2.jpg';
$ch = curl_init($imageURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $data;
curl_close($ch);
if ($data === false) {
        die('cURL failed');
}
if ( preg_match('/Content-length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches) || preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches) ) {
        $size = (int)$matches[1];
}   

$fileHandle = fopen($imageURL, 'rb'); //r or rb
$fileData = fread( $fileHandle, $size );
//echo $fileData;
fclose( $fileHandle );
$data = $fileData;

header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
echo $data;
```

[image]

Comment: What if you just `fread` until the end, without defined size?

Comment: @deceze i get "cannot be displayed because it containes errors"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why fetch it twice? Curl could do the job in one step. i.e.

```
$imageURL = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Tibia_insulaechorab_transparent.png/320px-Tibia_insulaechorab_transparent.png';
$ch = curl_init($imageURL);    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($data === false) {
        die('cURL failed');
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Length: ' . curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD ) );
echo $data;
```

Comment: you can determine the real size of your file using `strlen($data)`

Comment: yeah, `curl_getinfo` would also work, might be even better because in the php settings you could overload PHP's `strlen` function with the `mb_strlen` replacement of the `mb_string extension` which would not necessarily return the correct value

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageURL = 'http://ec2-**-***-**-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com/New_Era_For_NASA_2.jpg';
$ch = curl_init($imageURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
curl_close($ch);
```

Would be enough

```
file_get_content( $imageURL );
```

Would work to0 but be aware of memory_limit, fread might be a better option.